# Forwarding external domain to GCP Instance with https

Tags: https, dns, virtual-machine, instance, forwarding

What is the easiest way to route an externally hosted domain to my VM instance on GCP (with a fixed IP) and connect over HTTPS? Currently only HTTP works, forwarded via the entry in the A Records. Which service is best suited for this on GCP?  I am happy about every suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can point your domain to VM via adding `A` record in DNS. For managing the https you can setup the nginx or apache and generate or add the SSL/TLS certificate there.

For generating free SSL/TLS certificate you can use : https://certbot.eff.org/

it's easy to manage and install the SSL/TLS certificate with `certbot` also it's having functionality of auto-renewal of certificates.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much. Certbot looks good. :)

A) Currently I have the following configuration:

1. Domain at Active24 (A record points to server)
2. Server is Alfresco on a VM instance on GCP
3. Server is Apache Tomcat on Debian 9
4. I can manage on the command line, but it's not my daily business.
5. I installed Certbot and had the certificate installed (`sudo certbot --apache`)

B) Now, after installing Certbot, here's the situation:

1. When I open the URL/Domain I get to the Alfresco Login Screen. Browser does not show HTTPS.
2. After entering my login data, HTTPS appears, but I cannot access the Share environment. Instead I see an Alfresco error page with a button to return to the dashboard.
3. When I click on the "Back to Dashboard" button, I return to the login screen.

I think I still have to configure Apache to forward to the appropriate destinations. But I can't find any instructions for this.

C) My next questions are:

1. Did Certbot install an additional server as a proxy, or did it configure the existing one?
2. In which directory do I find the appropriate server settings?

Thanks a lot!